# Android - Time Comparison "hh:mm:ss a" format

Tags: android, time

"I try to compare two time in "hh:mm:ss a" format. But it not really work in what I think. I googled but couldn't find a proper answer. Sorry cause I'm new to programming."

I try to compare the time like this:

```
String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SCHEDULE + " WHERE lecturer_id=? AND schedule_day=? AND schedule_endtime > ?";
```

**schedule_endtime > ?**

However, the comparison has ignored the AM/PM which caused the result become like this:
**eg.  12:00:00 PM is bigger than 02:00:00 PM.**

Hope that you all can give some tips or provide some solution. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of comparing the formatted string, compare the value in milliseconds. Take a look at this to [convert the string back to date](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then once you have two dates you can compare them like so:

```
 boolean before = someDate.before(anotherDate);
```

or

```
 boolean after = someDate.after(anotherDate);
```

or even

```
 someDate.getTime() < anotherDate.getTime();
```

Side note: when I store dates, I like to just store the millisecond value and the time zone. That way you don't need to worry about things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the SQLite database you are storing the dates as Strings, not as a Date because in SQLite doesn't exist a Date type (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

You have two options: change the column type to a INTEGER type and store de date as a number (then you can compare milliseconds) or get the entity as it is, parse a Date type with the String, create a SimpleDateFormat with the given format and then make the comparison.