# Comparing two time strings in java

Tags: java

Given two strings like `02:03:45` and `10:04:20` which represents `hh:mm:ss`
Is there any efficient way to determine which is lesser and which is more?

**My thoughts:**
I thought of splitting them by `:` and then checking. But I was wondering if

 there is a neat way to do it

Comment: How about using [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) on the strings? Doesn't that give you the answer you want?

Comment: If the time is formatted in 24 hours format and you only want to know which one is lesser/greater you can simply use the String `compareTo` method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-

Comment: Just convert them to `LocalTime` (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788369/coverting-string-to-localtime-with-without-nanoofseconds) and compare them.

Comment: Please visit this link
[Android - Time Comparison “hh:mm:ss a” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883783/android-time-comparison-hhmmss-a-format) I hope it works.

Comment: @user16320675 If the OP's strings did not have leading zeroes, I would not have suggested it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in that way:

```
 LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse("02:03:45");
 LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse("10:04:20");
```

an then call: `time1.compareTo(time2)`

Comment: In addition, you can call `time1.isBefore(time2)` or `time2.isAfter(time1)`